Android how to get an image from a mediastore made Uri?
I created and stored an image like this:
    val values = ContentValues(2)
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
    picUri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)

    Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
            takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {   
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri )
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE)
        }
    }

Then I have to reuse this pic later. I need to feed its content into a WebResourceResponse in a custom WebViewClient::shouldInterceptRequest()
I need an input stream to do a return WebResourceResponse("image/jpeg", "utf-8", inputStream)
The path looks like this: /external/images/media/40
How do I get an inputStream from a content://external/images/media/40 uri?
Or how do I request the MediaStore so it finds my pic?
What I tried (under many other failed tries):
        val uriString = "content:/" + path //results in content://external/images/media/40
        val uri = Uri.parse(uriString) 
        val inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        if(inputStream==null) return WebResourceResponse("image/jpeg", "utf-8", ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOf()))//return empty image (404 would trigger onReceivedHttpError)
        return WebResourceResponse("image/jpeg", "utf-8", inputStream)

I get following Error in Logcat: "Failed to find provider info for external".
Followed by "Client raised exception in shouldInterceptRequest. Re-throwing on UI thread."
Then "The following exception was raised by shouldInterceptRequest:" (nothing after the colon).
I finally found out that:
Log.d("x", uriString) ==> content://external/images/media/47  but
Log.d("x", uri!!.path!!) ==> /images/media/47
then, that:
Log.d("x", picUri.path)==> /external/images/media/47  but
Log.d("x", picUri.toString)==> content://media/external/images/media/47
So this is this missing "media/" part that was the whole problem.
When adding it, everything works!
What I learned today is that an android Uri is not a scheme + a path, but a scheme [+ hidden things] + a path.
I'll base my processes on uri.toString() instead of uri.path and everything should be fine!
Many thanks @CommonsWare

getContentResolver().openInputStream() is how you get an InputStream on a content Uri, assuming that the Uri actually represents something openable that way. You indicate that this "failed" -- what were your results, specifically? Also, have you tried creating a Uri by other means, such as using FileProvider?

sorry, I edited to reflect error information, as well as where val uri comes from.
"Have you tried...": do you mean when savig the image or when trying to access it?

It should be the same Uri in both places.

In my context, the picture is requested from javascript through a javascriptInterface: all I can return to JS is a string, so I returned the Uri.path. Then Javascript requests the image itself using an http URL, which is intercepted in a custom WebViewClient (shouldInterceptRequest()). At this point I don't have the original content Uri instance any more, I have to reforge it from the string JS sends me back. It worked nicely before Q and all this content/provider/mediastore stuff. With Q I find no way to send a string to JS of which I can re-find my image again later on :-(

JS uses https:/ /my.domain.com/LOCALFILE/xx/yy/zz where xx/yy/zz is equal to picUri.path (see first snippet abt picUri). Here I must find a way in shouldInterceptRequest() to access the image with this xx/yy/zz path. I'm open to any suggestion abt WHAT string I could pass to JS and then back, if the Uri.path is not the right idea...

"I returned the Uri.path" -- I would return the entire Uri as a string, using toString(). "At this point I don't have the original content Uri instance any more" -- if you give it the full Uri as a string, you should get back that full Uri as a string, and you can convert it into a Uri via Uri.parse(). Alternatively, you can give JS whatever string you want, and use that as a key to a Map<String, Uri> to get the full Uri. Regardless, you need the full original Uri, and I think yours is missing some stuff.

That's exactly what I was beginning to find out... there's strangely a "media/" missing between picUri.toString() and picUri.path

Just use the returned content Uri without any messing around; ContentResolver does all of this.

Cannot have a http://my.domain.com/local/content://media/external/... url in my html. At least I must get rid of content:// => http://my.domain.com/local/media/external/...
Then in WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest() I'm able to serve the local file transparently, JS is not even aware of the substitution. So I actually have to "mess around" with the Uri, but now based on Uri.toString() and just removing content://, it works like a charm
